# How to exit Python Script from Terminal

Tags: python

so I am trying to run a python script from terminal and at the end it does not exit the process unit I hit `ENTER`. I tried to kill the process and use the following, `sys.exit()`, `quit()`, `raise SystemExit` but nothing seem to work. Below is the code I am using. Any ideas please?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess, sys, os
from sys import exit
firstarg=sys.argv[1]
service_provider = subprocess.Popen (['ffprobe', '-loglevel', 'fatal', '-select_streams', '-show_entries', 'program_tags', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0"), '-i', sys.argv[1]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = service_provider.communicate() [0]
result = out.split('\n')
a = str(result [0])
b = str(result [1])
cmds1 = ['ffmpeg', '-i', sys.argv[1], '-c', 'copy', '-out1.ts']
cmds2 = ['ffmpeg', '-i', sys.argv[1], '-c', 'copy', '-out2.ts']
subprocess.Popen(cmds1)
subprocess.Popen(cmds2)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: you have to catch KeyboardInterrupt exception and stop subprocesses

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I managed to get it working by adding the following to the code,

```
out = cmds1.communicate()
cmds1.kill()
```

not sure if this is the clean way of doing. Its doing the job but I am getting the following error at the end just before it exits,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest8.py", line 23, in <module>
    cmds1.kill()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1564, in kill
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1554, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```